# Static data lost after android service restart

Tags: java, android, android-activity, static, android-service

My Android application starts a local foreground service (in the same process as my activity). The service have to stay alive, even if the system destroys the activity due low memory.

Next time a user starts the app, I need to check whether the service is running or not.
I tried to store state in `public static boolean Started = false;` flag in service class (I know that it is bad practice).

My activity starts in the process where service is running. I thought, that static constructor is called ones. So, I would be able to check this flag in activity. However, static data is reinitialized to defaults.

Could any one give me a cue about this behavior?

Comment: Try to store data in shared preferences for future usage....

Comment: its fine if restart service if apps come to foreground?

Comment: I'm using intent service, so every time apps go foreground i stop then start the service

Comment: I wrote some answer, so easily for you to copy it

Comment: The reason I created a service is to minimize a chance it be destroyed. So, it should keep running until it is explicitly stopped by user. I need persist data while service is running. Data have to be reinitialized if new process starts.

Comment: The bottom line of the question is to know static classes life circle when different components start in existing process. Is it common java behavior or android specific? Actually, I have other options to find out whether the service is running. However, it would be nice to here all alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

here is just an example how I restart the service when apps come forground

```
public void storeLastLocation() {
    if (!isStoreLocationActive){
        Log.d("IQ MA", "storeLastLocation() called");

        String access_token = Configs.access_token;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoreLocationService.class);
        intent.putExtra("access_token", access_token);
        stopService(intent);
        startService(intent);

        isStoreLocationActive = true;
    }
}
```

then store boolean on service is running